# MySQL column containing different Java datatypes

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table in my MySQL containing calculated values. At the moment this is a `Decimal` field.
But now I'll need this table to also hold calculated dates, booleans etc.

What's the best solution here, just change the MySQL field type to a `VARCHAR` and handle the rest in my Java code. Or am I gonna get me in a mess with this approach?

Any ideas and pointers are welcome!

Comment: Can you add some more columns to your table to hold the new data types?

Comment: This is a poor design. SQL likes one datatype per column, and so does Java really.

Comment: So the only solution is adding a column for each possible datatype?

Comment: Maybe not. Maybe the solution is to redesign the problem completely. How exactly did you get into this mess?

Comment: I'm working on something that already existed, so no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single column per datatype and introduce a discriminator column stating which of the datatype columns should be referenced.  The discriminator column can simply be an int representing an enumeration of possible datatypes.

Comment: Hmm, was also thinking of this, guess that's what I'll have to do then.